# Desktop notification - display time

Tags: node-webkit

I have a problem with the standard node-webkit notifications. I'm using version 0.10.5 and when i'm trying to put notifications something like that:

new Notification("Hello world!");

then i get the notification, but after a short time disappears. Is there any possibility to increase this time and run something function after click on notification?

Greetings

Comment: I changed this time in windows option so topic is closed.